# porting to ARM-LINUX

Tags: linux, sdk, gdb, arm

I am trying to port an application to ARM_LINUX platform.
I have copied all the cross-compiled libraries to target. The program starts 
and crashes.

I am debugging remotely with gdb.

There are two things,

1. While calling a library function the return value is -1 hence the program terminates with gdb exit code **0377**.

I inserted break points and used backtrace but none of it helped, or may be someone could help me how to resolve this ?
LD_DEBUG stops while binding one of the symbols .. what does that mean ?

2. I removed error handling and when the program proceeds I get a segmentation fault.

Which of the scenarios is better to debug ? Is it because of library mismatch ?
Could anyone help me with some tips ? FYI the application is built using shared libraries.

Thanks in advance,
Praveen

Comment: Try to use ldd to see what libraries your program depends on. Check their paths, versions and make sure it's using the expected ones.

Comment: when I use ldd it shows a list of dependencies. I have use the exact same list and copied on the target. Dynamic linker will generate an error if all the libraries are not present.